# Rancher Load Balancer setup with EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nat, rancher

I have an infrastructure in aws as follows: a rancher server(v2.7), two EKS clusters each one with three Ec2 and for the DNS I have a domain in cloudflare.

My question is, how can I use the rancher loadbalancer with the domains from cloudflare to redirect to the services in rancher. In a previous infrastructure that I had I used NAT in the firewall with the rancher sever as the translated destination (DNAT) but I dont know how to replicate that in the AWS.

I tried the following: https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/getting-started/installation-and-upgrade/install-upgrade-on-a-kubernetes-cluster/rancher-on-amazon-eks

The problem with this solution is that I needed to migrate the domain to route 53 which is not possible at the moment. I need to find a way to keep the domain in cloudflare and still can reach the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I used the link in the question(https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/getting-started/installation-and-upgrade/install-upgrade-on-a-kubernetes-cluster/rancher-on-amazon-eks) to create the nginx-ingress. Then i used the external IP generated and add two CNAME in cloudflare pointing to the external IP(which is something like .....us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com).

Finally in the rancher I created an ingress for the subdomain assign to the CNAME i created in the cloudflare and configure the Ingress Class to be nginx.

I hope that helps everyone who is dealing with the same situation.